# React-Bootstrap 1.0.0-beta.6 offset and Form Col not working

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I just install react-bootstrap v1.0.0-beta.6 and the Grid system is not working. I copied the following code from their documentation but it is not working.

I am trying to centralize the form in the screen by using offsets and I also want some of the form fields to be adjacent each other.

```
class RegistrationPage extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Container>
        <Row center>
          <Col md={{ span: 4, offset: 4}}>
            <Form>
              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridEmail">
                  <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridPassword">
                  <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>

              <Form.Group controlId="formGridAddress1">
                <Form.Label>Address</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control placeholder="1234 Main St" />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Group controlId="formGridAddress2">
                <Form.Label>Address 2</Form.Label>
                <Form.Control placeholder="Apartment, studio, or floor" />
              </Form.Group>

              <Form.Row>
                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridCity">
                  <Form.Label>City</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control />
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridState">
                  <Form.Label>State</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control as="select">
                    <option>Choose...</option>
                    <option>...</option>
                  </Form.Control>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group as={Col} controlId="formGridZip">
                  <Form.Label>Zip</Form.Label>
                  <Form.Control />
                </Form.Group>
              </Form.Row>

              <Form.Group id="formGridCheckbox">
                <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Check me out" />
              </Form.Group>

              <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                Submit
              </Button>
            </Form>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the result...

[image]

Notice how the form does not have columns and the form is not centralized.

I am using  `"bootstrap": "^4.3.1"`

Comment: Did you imported the proper bootstrap style (scss or simple css) in your project?

Answer (score -1):

I just had this answered on the gitHub page. I installed bootstrap but had not imported it in my index.js as shown [here](https://facebook.github.io/create-react-app/docs/adding-bootstrap)